# Disable 'Do not ask again' on delete confirmation

Tags: kde-plasma-5, dolphin-file-manager

Is there a way to remove the `Do not ask again` checkbox on the `are you sure?` dialogue when deleting files?

[image]

I'm an avid shift-deleter and really need this last safety net, it would be really bad to one day accidentally check it without noticing.

As a secondary question, though, if I ticked it but realised after dismissing the the prompt, how would one get it to start asking `are you sure?` again?

Answer (score 4):

Start typing 'Dolphin' or 'General' in Kickoff and choose this window and 'Confirmations' tab for settings adjustment (see attachment):

[image: Dolphin General]